# Places SDK in android

Tags: java, android

I have implemented the new Place SDK since the last one is going to be deprecated for good.

But now in `setOnPlaceSelectedListener` function I am getting this error:

```
 SetOnPlaceSelectedListener
 (com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.listener.PlaceSelectionListener)
 in AutocompleteSupportFragment cannot be applied to (anonymous
 com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener)
```

Comment: Check your `import`.

Comment: you are using a different class, but the name is the same. Import the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

hi try this it may help you

```
 AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                    .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_COUNTRY)
                    .setCountry("PK")
                    .build();
            Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
//                    .setFilter(typeFilter)
                    .setBoundsBias(new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), new LatLng(latitude, longitude)))
                    .build(getActivity());
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);




@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(context, data);
                CharSequence destination = place.getName();
                LatLng destination_LatLng = place.getLatLng();
                latitude = destination_LatLng.latitude;
                longitude = destination_LatLng.longitude;

            }
        }
    }
```